# How to redirect to parent route if page doesn't exist?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say I have these routes:

```
<Route
    path="/subpage/:slug"
    component={SubPageDetail}
    key="subpage-detail"
/>

<Route
    path="/subpage"
    component={SubPage}
    key="subpage"
/>
```

For the `:slug`, we have certain pages that have a match e.g. `/subpage/subpage-info1`. However, if someone types gibberish as in: `/subpage/fhfjadsf33`, which doesn't exist, we want to redirect that user to the immediate parent which is `/subpage` (not the homepage or anything).

How do we achieve that in react-router?

Comment: You could have some logic in `SubPageDetail` to figure out if `:slug` is gibberish or not, and either redirect the user with `this.props.history` or rendering `<Redirect to="/subpage" />` in the `SubPageDetail` render method.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do, is to add this route

```
<Route component = { ComponentError } />
```

Of corse, you have to create the ComponentError to show your page error or whatever you want.
But still, you will have a problem, the ComponentError will alwasye show in every page, to adjust this, you have to wrape your routes inside a switch tag like this.

```
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom"
...
...

<Switch>
<Route path="/subpage" component={SubPage} />
<Route component = { ComponentError } />
</Switch>
```

Of corse I would like to clarify that it is available on react Router V4.
Hope it will help.

Sorry I forgot to mention, that all you have to do, I think is to change this CompoenentError with your component subPage.
Like this, it will help you, and help others that want to achieve athores goal with that method

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either you let react-router check if the route has been defined and if not, redirects the user to a default component. Or you can have logic in your code to check the url. I think the first option is the easiest.

Just add a route like so :

```
<Route path='*' exact={true} component={MyDefaultComponent} />
```